# Helm appears to parse my chart differently depending on if I use --dry-run --debug?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

So I was deploying a new cronjob today and got the following error:

```
Error: release acs-export-cronjob failed: CronJob.batch "acs-export-cronjob" is invalid: [spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers: Required value, spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", "Never"]
```

here's some output from running helm on the same chart, no changes made, but with the `--debug --dry-run` flags:

```
 NAME:   acs-export-cronjob
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Wed Oct 17 14:12:02 2018
CHART: generic-job-0.1.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
applicationName: users
command: publishAllForRealm
image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
jobAppArgs: ""
jobVmArgs: ""
jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
name: acs-export-cronjob
schedule: 0 * * * *

COMPUTED VALUES:
applicationName: users
command: publishAllForRealm
image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
jobAppArgs: ""
jobVmArgs: ""
jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
name: acs-export-cronjob
resources:
cpu: 100m
memory: 1Gi
schedule: 0 * * * *
sonicNodeGroup: api
springProfiles: export-job

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-sa
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
resources: ["deployments"]
verbs: ["get"]
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
name: acs-export-cronjob-sa
roleRef:
kind: Role
name: acs-export-cronjob-manager
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/generic-job.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob
labels:
    app: generic-job
    chart: "generic-job-0.1.0"
    release: "acs-export-cronjob"
    heritage: "Tiller"
spec:
schedule: 0 * * * *
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
startingDeadlineSeconds: 120
jobTemplate:
    spec:
    metadata:
        name: acs-export-cronjob
        labels:
        jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
        app: generic-job
        chart: "generic-job-0.1.0"
        release: "acs-export-cronjob"
        heritage: "Tiller"
    spec:
        template:
        metadata:
            labels:
            jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
            app: generic-job
            chart: "generic-job-0.1.0"
            release: "acs-export-cronjob"
            heritage: "Tiller"
            annotations:
            iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::<censored>:role/k8s-service-role
        spec:
            restartPolicy: Never   #<----------this is not 'Always'!!
            serviceAccountName: acs-export-cronjob-sa
            tolerations:
            - key: sonic-node-group
            operator: Equal
            value: api
            effect: NoSchedule
            nodeSelector:
            sonic-node-group: api
            volumes:
            - name: config
            emptyDir: {}
            initContainers:
            - name: "get-users-vmargs-from-deployment"
            image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/utils/kubectl-helm:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl -n eu1-test get deployment users-vertxapp -o jsonpath=\"{..spec.containers[0].env[?(@.name=='APP_SPECIFIC_VM_ARGS')].value}\" > /config/users-vmargs && cat /config/users-vmargs"]
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            - name: "get-users-yaml-appconfig-from-deployment"
            image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/utils/kubectl-helm:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl -n eu1-test get deployment users-vertxapp -o jsonpath=\"{..spec.containers[0].env[?(@.name=='APP_YAML_CONFIG')].value}\" > /config/users-appconfig && cat /config/users-appconfig"]
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            containers:     #<--------this field is not missing!
            - image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: "users-batch"
            command:
            - "bash"
            - "-c"
            - 'APP_SPECIFIC_VM_ARGS="$(cat /config/users-vmargs) " APP_YAML_CONFIG="$(cat /config/users-appconfig)" /vertx-app/startvertx.sh'
            env:
            - name: FRENV
                value: "batch"
            - name: STACKNAME
                value: eu1-test
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES
                value: "export-job"
            - name: NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            resources:
                limit:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 1Gi
```

if you paid attention, you may have noticed line 101 (I added the comment afterwards) in the debug-output, which sets `restartPolicy` to `Never`, quite the opposite of `Always` as the error message claims it to be.

You may also have noticed line 126 (again, I added the comment after the fact) of the debug output, where the mandatory field `containers` is specified, again, much in contradiction to the error-message.

whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hah! found it! it was a simple mistake actually. I had an extra `spec:metadata` section under `jobtemplate` which was duplicated. removing one of the dupes fixed my issues.

I really wish the error-messages of helm would be more helpful.

the corrected chart looks like:

```
 NAME:   acs-export-cronjob
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Wed Oct 17 14:12:02 2018
CHART: generic-job-0.1.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
applicationName: users
command: publishAllForRealm
image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
jobAppArgs: ""
jobVmArgs: ""
jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
name: acs-export-cronjob
schedule: 0 * * * *

COMPUTED VALUES:
applicationName: users
command: publishAllForRealm
image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
jobAppArgs: ""
jobVmArgs: ""
jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
name: acs-export-cronjob
resources:
cpu: 100m
memory: 1Gi
schedule: 0 * * * *
sonicNodeGroup: api
springProfiles: export-job

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-sa
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
resources: ["deployments"]
verbs: ["get"]
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/rbac.yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
name: acs-export-cronjob-sa
roleRef:
kind: Role
name: acs-export-cronjob-manager
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
# Source: generic-job/templates/generic-job.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
name: acs-export-cronjob
labels:
    app: generic-job
    chart: "generic-job-0.1.0"
    release: "acs-export-cronjob"
    heritage: "Tiller"
spec:
schedule: 0 * * * *
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
startingDeadlineSeconds: 120
jobTemplate:
   spec:
      template:
         metadata:
            labels:
            jobgroup: acs-export-jobs
            app: generic-job
            chart: "generic-job-0.1.0"
            release: "acs-export-cronjob"
            heritage: "Tiller"
            annotations:
            iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::<censored>:role/k8s-service-role
        spec:
            restartPolicy: Never   
            serviceAccountName: acs-export-cronjob-sa
            tolerations:
            - key: sonic-node-group
            operator: Equal
            value: api
            effect: NoSchedule
            nodeSelector:
            sonic-node-group: api
            volumes:
            - name: config
            emptyDir: {}
            initContainers:
            - name: "get-users-vmargs-from-deployment"
            image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/utils/kubectl-helm:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl -n eu1-test get deployment users-vertxapp -o jsonpath=\"{..spec.containers[0].env[?(@.name=='APP_SPECIFIC_VM_ARGS')].value}\" > /config/users-vmargs && cat /config/users-vmargs"]
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            - name: "get-users-yaml-appconfig-from-deployment"
            image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/utils/kubectl-helm:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl -n eu1-test get deployment users-vertxapp -o jsonpath=\"{..spec.containers[0].env[?(@.name=='APP_YAML_CONFIG')].value}\" > /config/users-appconfig && cat /config/users-appconfig"]
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            containers:     
            - image: <censored>.amazonaws.com/sonic/acs-export:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: "users-batch"
            command:
            - "bash"
            - "-c"
            - 'APP_SPECIFIC_VM_ARGS="$(cat /config/users-vmargs) " APP_YAML_CONFIG="$(cat /config/users-appconfig)" /vertx-app/startvertx.sh'
            env:
            - name: FRENV
                value: "batch"
            - name: STACKNAME
                value: eu1-test
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES
                value: "export-job"
            - name: NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
                name: config
            resources:
                limit:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to formatting error.
Look at the examples [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-cron-jobs-455fdc32e81a) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job).
The structure is

```
jobTemplate:  
    spec:  
      template:  
        spec:  
          restartPolicy: Never
```

As per provided output you have `spec` and `restartPolicy` on the same line:

```
jobTemplate:
       spec:
        template:
        spec:
            restartPolicy: Never   #<----------this is not 'Always'!!
```

The same with `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers`
Suppose helm uses some default values instead of yours.
You can also try to generate yaml file, convert it to json and apply.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you mean. They're not on the same line, and they're not on the same indentation level...could you clarify? thanks for your answer though